# Best way to check for duplicated records

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have two tables `A` and `B` with a relationship of One-to-many from `A` to `B`.

A has 5 columns:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
```

and B has 5 columns

```
b1, b2, b3, b4, a1.
```

Note `a1` is foreign key in table B.

I have a requirement to check duplicate records in the table  i.e. no two records should have exactly same values for all the attributes.

The most efficient way I can think of for determining their uniqueness is by creating a checksum sort of value and keep it in every row of table A. But this requires extra space plus I will have to make sure that the checksum is really unique.

Is this the best way to go ahead or is there some other way I am unaware of?

For e.g. Lets say table `A` is `Rules` Table and Table `B` is `Trigger` table. Now `Rules` table has records of various rules created by different users.(This means that there will be a mapping to `Users` Table in `Rules` Table.). Now what I actually want is that a user should not be able to create identical rules. So when a user saves rules I run a query to check if there is record of identical checksum for this particular user if yes then I give the appropriate error otherwise I let the user to create the record.I guess this clears that why I can't put unique constraint on all records.

Comment: Skip the check-sum. (Must be managed using triggers.) Why not a unique constraint instead, i.e. `unique(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)`.

Comment: Sample data and expected results might be helpful here...

Comment: Are you wanting to eliminate existing duplicates? identify them for removal or prevent them from occurring in the first place? (1,2 all 3?)

Comment: @jarlh using triggers wont give me error when inserting record with hibernate or would it ?

Comment: @xQbert I want to prevent them from occurring in first place.

Comment: and adding sample data too ...

Comment: I don't like the trigger based check-sum solution. Unique constraint is the way to go.

Comment: please check the edit, I have tried to explain my problem with an example.. I have explained why I cant put unique constraint

Comment: I still don't see why.   Since the unique constraint involve the foreign key user, you have uniqueness for each user; though rules could be duplicated.  This seems to meet all the criteria as I read it.

Comment: You talk about "similar".  There is a _huge_ difference between testing for identically equal and testing for "similar".

Comment: yeah ! sorry about that , changed that in the latest edit !

Answer (score 1):

Do a SELECT with a GROUP BY clause. For example:

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, COUNT(*) FROM #TempPersons GROUP BY a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will return a result with the a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 and a count of how many times that value appears

Comment: Actually this wont help me much because I have to do a check sort of thing. Before inserting a new record I want to check whether this sort of data already exists for a particular user, I am updating my question for more details.

Comment: No, Furquand.  You perform the `INSERT`.  If you get a "dup key" error, you spit at the user.  If you don't get that error, then it is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Having a UNIQUE constraint on those columns seems like the way to go.

However, just for the sake of answering your other remarks: I've worked with extra columns to check for changes in the past before. Back then I did something similar to this:

```
CONVERT([NVARCHAR](42),HASHBYTES('SHA1',CONCAT(Column1, '||', Column2, ...),(1))
```

I found it to be a rather nice way to concat many columns into a single hash, unique depending on it's contents & without it blowing out of proportion. (I used this in a datawarehousing environment, to check large tables for record level changes based on a business key. Stored this as a PERSISTED column to allow an index to run on this too).